# Is there any way to display terminal output value on Linux(Ubuntu 20.04) window top bar(GNOME Shell)?

Tags: linux, display, ubuntu-20.04, gnome-shell, network-monitoring

Is there any way to display terminal output value on Linux(Ubuntu 20.04) window top bar(GNOME Shell) ?first of all i just need to view `vnstat -t` this outcome continually.
this command terminal output like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOHTx.png)

I tried for using of a tool called **"Argos"**. I Created an Argos script to display the terminal output value as following

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(vnstat -t)"
```

but it look like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxIEs.png).

but i need this type of view [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkuwj.png).

how ever i need to track internet usage(download & upload) by daily is there any way to do this or how to solve this issue.???

Comment: There is probably an application that will do that for you. With a mac there is the `stats` so that might be a name to search for. .... Needing to include screenshots in your question here on StackOverflow (S.O.) is almost always a clue you are posting to the wrong site on StackExchange network. S.O. is about helping readers fix `if/then/else` programming code. Your question might be a better fit on [unix.se] or [su], but read their help about on-topic questions and decide on one site. Don't cross post, it makes some people very angry (-;. Please delete this Q here. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter [link](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/2702526/21953508/7463004c-da5f-11e6-99e1-b8db1167c071.gif)  _**i need this type of view**_